# Running a Bash expression from sudo

Tags: bash, sudo

I can list my recent apt-get history with:-

```
zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

I am trying to automate this for all history files.

I tried:

```
sudo for logf in $( /var/log/apt/history.log.?.gz ); do zcat $logf ; done
```

but get error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token do`

```
for logf in $( /var/log/apt/history.log.?.gz ); do zcat $logf ; done
```

but get error `-bash: /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz: Permission denied`

```
for logf in $( /var/log/apt/history.log.?.gz ); do sudo zcat $logf ; done
```

but get error `-bash: /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz: Permission denied`

Comment: Try `for logf in /var/log/apt/history.log.?.gz ; ...` but for output only is enough `sudo zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.?.gz`

Comment: @Costas Thanks - both worked. I thought I had tried the 1st in one of my dozens of other attempts. The 2nd also works, but I really wanted to do some more in the `do` but simplified when I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` works with binaries only but not for shell command structures. You have to run the whole thing with `sudo`. It doesn't make much sense to call `sudo` several times within a loop. It may cache the password, though.

```
sudo bash -c 'for logf in /var/log/apt/history.log.?.gz; do zcat "$logf"; done'
```